# How to call a Javascript function with closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

Version 1

```js
function sayHello2(name){
  var text='Hello'+name;
  var say=function(){
   console.log(text);
    
  };
 return say;
  
}

var say2=sayHello2("David");
say2();
```

Version 2

```js
function sayHello2(name){
  var text='Hello'+name;
  var say=function(){
   console.log(text);
    
  };
 return say;
  
}

sayHello2("David")();
```

Questions:

1. Why in version one, when you use var say2 to call sayHello2, you don't have to add another set of empty parentheses?
2. If I take off the line return say;, the error message will say sayHello2 is not a function, why?
3. Why is the point of say2(); (the last line in version2)? If I delete that line, nothing changes, 'HelloDavid' will still be logged.

Comment: Only difference is one  you store the first step into a variable and than call it. Second one just des not use a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In both samples of code, **two** function calls are made. The difference between the first and second is that in the first sample, the result of the first function call is stored in `say2` before the second function call is made. The second sample immediately uses the return value from `sayHello2()` to call that returned function.
2. If there's no `return` statement, then `sayHello2()` returns `undefined`.
3. The claim of this question, that removing the `say2();` line does not change the behavior, is incorrect. If you don't call `say2()` then nothing will be logged.

Look at `sayHello2()`:

```
function sayHello2(name){
  // Initialize the text that will be logged
  var text='Hello'+name;

  // Create the function that will log the message
  var say=function(){
    console.log(text);
  };

  // Return the logging function
  return say;
}
```

The `sayHello2()` function returns a reference to that little function that calls `console.log()`. Because functions are object values in JavaScript, a reference to a function works as well as any other sort of value, and can be stored in a variable or used in an expression.

Note that when the logging function is created, that's done with a `var` initailization:

```
  var say=function(){
    console.log(text);
  };
```

That's essentially the same thing that happens to the variable `say2`:

```
var say2=sayHello2("David");
```

except that here, on the right-hand side of the `=` sign there's a function *call* instead of a function instantiation.

The statement

```
say2();
```

therefore is calling that little logging function that was returned from the call to `sayHello2()`.

The second code sample does the same thing:

```
sayHello2("David")();
```

except that there's no intermediate storage of the returned function reference. Instead, the reference is immediately used to make the second function call.

In the first version, count the function calls made:

```
var say2 = sayHello2("David"); // First function call
say2(); // Second function call
```

In the second version:

```
// First          // Second
sayHello2("David")();
```

In JavaScript, an expression of the form

```
something()
```

always means, "Interpret `something` as a reference to a function, and call it (passing no parameters)."  If `something` is not a reference to a function, you get an exception. So in version 2, our `something` is `sayHello2("David")`. Because that's got the second set of empty parentheses after it, it means we're telling JavaScript to make another function call.

Comment: But what is purpose of say2();?

Comment: I am still not clear about what you said "The second sample immediately uses the return value from sayHello2() to call that returned function.".What returned function?And what is return value?

Comment: @user132522 `sayHello2()` returns a reference to a **function**. That reference is stored in the variable `say2`, so `say2()` makes a **call** to that function.

Comment: @user132522 I will add more explanation to the answer.

Comment: THank you. Can you explicitly refer to the part of my code you are talking about. I am not good with terms.

Comment: So the second function call displays the string. And that empty second set of parentheses is for that purpose? I thought that empty set is there because there is a inner function.

Comment: @user132522 Yes, the second `()` in version 2 do exactly what the `()` after `say2` do in version 1.

Comment: One more thing, what happens when you return a function? If I make a function Add(a,b){ return a+b;} I can understand that as what is returned is a number.

Comment: @user132522 a reference to a function is essentially the same as a reference to a plain object, at least as far as simple assignments and `return` statements. So returning a function as a value is not much different than that `var say = function ...` statement.